# how to determine a user agent is android?

Tags: android, http-headers, user-agent

My web server want distinct android device request with others.
I have noticed http `user-agent` is a good way to do. But I'm not sure which regular method can distinct `user-agent` string.Or any other ways also welcome.Thanks
**Update**
I know client can override the keywords.But,in the situation,client is our own app so ignore the problem is not a big problem.: )

Comment: I have check many android platform's default user-agent value, the keyword "Android" able to much almost android platform.If you situation like me, android app is developing by our company self, I think the best way to clarify this is to append some information at `user-agent`.

Answer (score 1):

`Android` is not something that has a user-agent, it is OS. The Web-browser application has a user-agent property. And each developer can freely set user agent of his own app to anything, even to smth. like `Albus Dumbledore`, or `Tony Stark`. You unfortunately can't determine 100% if it is Android, or not because noone has to tell you this. The best what you can do is to collect a list of `User-Agent` of the most popular Android web browser apps, and check from this list.

Comment: hi, I have see [google android string](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent) and [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox) all of them can use `Android` as  a keyword.Google also gives a regex to match android device. Besides, client in android is our own app, so I can ignore client override by himself.I needn't exactly distinct what browser kind in android, just android is ok.does it haven't common method to match?